# Configuring Multi-factor authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In Identity Server features I see "Multi-factor authentication" but I don't see how to configure it in the product ! All I see is configuring a local authentication with either login/password or IWA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2IS does not support for multi-factor authentication by default. It has capabilities to support it.  Because you can implement and plug custom authenticators for WSO2IS. However there is no any multi-factor authenticator which is shipped with it.  But there is some plan to ship a `FIDO` authenticator with WSO2IS next release. Git from [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/tree/master/components/application-authenticators/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.fido).  However, WSO2IS can easily support multi-step authentication. It means that you can configure to authenticate the user from multiple IDPs as multiple steps.(Authenticate with FB and Google both)

Answer (score 1):

To have multi-factor authentication, add multiple identity providers to a single service provider.  An example of this is detailed [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/09/01/configure-multiple-federated-identity-providers-with-wso2-identity-server-wso2is/).  In that example, Asela shows how to set multiple federated providers as a choice, but they can be employed sequentially by adding additional 'authentication steps'.

Comment: For me it's not multi-factor authentication ! The definition is "Multi-factor authentication (MFA) is a method of computer access control which a user can pass by successfully presenting several separate authentication stages". I understand that we can configure multiple external IDP but I want to know if the internal WSO2 IDP (called local authentication) can perform multifactor authentication like PKI based or OTP, SMS challenge.... It could mean plug more authentication methods (not more Idp), defining authent chain, risk based authent....